# Why is this conditional expectation equal to this probability?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-probability

From [Stochastic Processes by Ross](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ealex2014/SPpdf/Stochastic%20Processes%20SM.pdf)

On page 75 (in the proof of lemma 2.3.4 on the bottom of page 74), the author writes at the bottom of the page:

> $P(Y_1 + \dots + Y_k < \tau_k, k = 1, \dots, n | \tau_n = u, Y_1 + \dots Y_n = y) = E[1 - \frac{Y_1 + \dots + Y_{n-1}}{\tau_n} | \tau_n = u,  Y_1 + \dots + Y_n = y]$

I can't figure out why this is the case, anyone have any ideas?

---

It seems the author is proving this by induction, but I can't figure out how these two things are equal. He shows that:

> $P(Y_1 + \dots Y_k < \tau_k, k = 1, \dots, n |Y_1 + \dots + Y_{n-1}, \tau_n u, Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) = 1-\frac{Y_1 + \dots + Y_{n-1}}{\tau_n}$

but I can't figure out how to prove that

> $E[P(Y_1 + \dots Y_k < \tau_k, k = 1, \dots, n |Y_1 + \dots + Y_{n-1}, \tau_n = u, Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) \space | \space \tau_n = u, Y_1 + \dots + Y_n = y]$
> $= P(Y_1 + \dots + Y_k < \tau_k, k = 1, \dots, n | \tau_n = u, Y_1 + \dots Y_n = y)$

The lemma restated here is:

> Let $\tau_1, \dots, \tau_n$ denote the ordered values from a set of $n$ independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables and let $Y_i, \dots, Y_n$ be iid nonnegative random variables that are also independent of $\{\tau_1, \dots, \tau_n\}.$  Then $P(Y_1 + \dots Y_k < \tau_k, k = 1, \dots, n | Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) = 1-y/t$ for $0 < y < t$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

If $g(B) = P(A|B, C=c)$ then $E(g(B)|C=c)= P(A|C=c)$.